# Why would using `select.select` prevent releasing a port/socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following code:

```
class Server:                                                                   
    def __init__(self, port, isWithThread):                                     
        self.isWithThread = isWithThread                                        
        self.port = port                                                        
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)           
        self.sock.setblocking(0)                                                
        log.info("Socket created...")                                           


    def __enter__(self):                                                        
        self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', self.port))                                
        self.sock.listen(5)                                                     
        log.info("Listening on %s:%s", '127.0.0.1', self.port)                  
        return self                                                             


    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):                                 
        self.sock.setblocking(1)                                                
        self.sock.close()                                                       
        log.info("Socket closed.")                                              
        log.info("Bye")                                                         


    def run(self):                                                              
        #client, addr = self.sock.accept()                                      
        log.info('Selecting...')                                                
        readers, writers, errors = select.select([self.sock], [], [], 10)          
        log.debug(readers)                                                      
        if readers:                                                             
            client, addr = readers[0].accept()                                  
            log.info('Client: %s', client.recv(2048).decode())                  
            client.sendall("Hippee!".encode())                                  
            client.close()                                                      
            log.info("Disconnected from %s:%s", *addr)
```

What's interesting about this is that when I have the `select.select` and `setblocking(0)`, it ends out keeping the address in use. If I remove the `setblocking` code and change the `run` function to:

```
def run(self):                                                              
    client, addr = self.sock.accept()                                      
    log.info('Client: %s', client.recv(2048).decode())                  
    client.sendall("Hippee!".encode())                                  
    client.close()                                                      
    log.info("Disconnected from %s:%s", *addr)
```

Then I can immediately re-run the server. With the `select()` call, I get the following error:

```
python3.3 test.py server
Socket created...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 89, in <module>
    with Server(12345, False) as s:
  File "test.py", line 57, in __enter__
    self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', self.port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

So why does it appear that the `select` is keeping my socket open, and how do I ensure it closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic. Magic is the only reason to see any difference with or without `select.select()`. According to [this page](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html), the reason that a socket will stay in use even after calling `.close()` is that the `TIME_WAIT` has not yet expired.

The solution is to use `.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`.

I tried this but it didn't work, and so I asked this question. Later, I realized that hey, I knew that things like Flask or SimpleHTTPServer will allow you to restart the server immediately. So I [used the source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html), and  examined the library code contained in `socketserver.py`. It was here that I discovered the use of `.setsocketopt()` but the call came **before** the call to `.bind()`.

To explain [setsocketopt()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt), let's see what does the docs say?

> **socket.setsockopt(level, optname, value)**
>   Set the value of the given socket option (see the Unix manual page setsockopt(2)). The needed symbolic constants are defined in the socket module (SO_* etc.). The value can be an integer or a string representing a buffer. In the latter case it is up to the caller to ensure that the string contains the proper bits (see the optional built-in module struct for a way to encode C structures as strings)

`level` refers to the [level of the TCP/IP stack](http://wiki.treck.com/Socket_Options) you want to talk about. In this case we don't want the IP layer but the socket itself. The socket option is `SO_REUSEADDR`, and we're setting the flag (value=1). So somewhere down in the kernel or drivers, we're effectively saying, "SHHhhhhhh... It's OK. I don't care that you're in `TIME_WAIT` right now. I want to `.bind()` to you anyway."

So I changed up my code to have:

```
sock.setsocketopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', self.port))
```

And it works perfectly.

\o/